# matlab: quantaize data and build an histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a 3D data (X,Y,Z). Where X is between 0 to 360, Y is between 0 to 180 and Z is between -100 to + 100.

I'd like to quantize the data to NxM scale values on X and Y axes respectively and to have some mean value for Z.

This data shall be displayed on 2D plot where the Z values shall be represented by colors (if value is close to 100, then green, if the value is close to -100 then red).
How this could be done?

I've seen that there is a `histogram2` function, but it doesn't take into account the z values.

Comment: Please add any attempts you have made since this will shed further light on the details of this task.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if you intend to do a histogram specifically but here is one way to plot a set of `z` values on a xy-plane. The plot is created by viewing a 3D surface plot from its top view to give the impression that it is 2D. The `view()` function takes to arguments that's used to set the `Angle` and `Elevation` the plot is observed from. The `colormap()` function can be used to set your colours depending on the amplitude/magnitude of variable `z`. Below I used random data as an example.

The topic about quantizing data seems  like it can be done by using a mean filter on blocks/windows of the `z` data. This will require more details and clarification. Any sample data will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Intensity Plot]

```
x = (0:360); 
y = (0:180);
z = (200*rand(length(y),length(x))) - 100;

[Time_Grid,Depth_Grid] = meshgrid(x,y);

surf(x,y,z);
title("Intensity Plot");
Angle = 0; Elevation = 90;
view(Angle,Elevation);

xlabel("x"); xlim([0,360]); 
ylabel("y"); ylim([0,180]);

red = [1 0 0]; green = [0 1 0]; blue = [0 0 1];

Colour_Palette = [red; blue; blue; blue; green];
colormap(Colour_Palette);
colorbar;
```